# Access property in array of object in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, erb

I'm fairly new to ruby on rails. I have a method that returns a an array of objects. Each object has a list of properties with an associated value. Here is an example of what an object looks like:

`#<People id: 1, name: "Person1", age: "10">`

In my controller I return this array of objects as `@array`. Then in my `.erb` file I have the following lines of code

```
<% @array.each do |a| %>
  <tr><td><%= a.name %></td></tr>
<% end %>
```

But when I run my code I get an error saying that `undefined method 'name'`.

I know the name property is in my array because right before I return `@array` I do `raise @array[0].name` and the correct names appears.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Unfortunately I cannot share my controller or Person class because it proprietary but I can show you the output of:

```
<% @array.each do |a| %>
      <tr><td><%= a %></td></tr>
    <% end %>
```

The above outputs:

`[0, #<People id: 1, name: "Person1", age: "10">]`

There is only 1 object in the array right now. Hopefully this helps. Again any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 2: I think it may have something to do with how I'm adding elements to `@array`.
This is how I'm adding elements to `@array`:

```
for idx in 0 ... @stats.size
  @array[idx] = Car.find(@stats[idx])
end
```

Comment: Could you please also post the controller code as well as your Person class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "array" isn't an array, it is a hash mapping numbers to objects. You need to fix your controller so it produces a proper array, or iterate over the hash correctly with `@array.each do |index, a|`.

Chances are pretty good that the line where you create `@array` looks like this

```
@array = {} # hash
```

Instead of like this:

```
@array = [] # array
```

How can I tell? `{0: 'blah'}.each { |a| p a }` will produce `[0, 'blah']`, the same way your first iteration produces `[0, #<Person...>]`. When you iterate over a hash with `each`, it effectively converts the hash from a `{key: value, key2: value2}` hash to a `[[key, value], [key2, value2]]` nested array, and splats each sub-array into the block. Since your block only accepts one argument, the `[key, value]` array isn't expanded, and you get both passed in `a`.

This is why you typically use `hash.each { |key,value|` to iterate over a hash.